# Getting Exception while trying to call a service over https

Tags: java, android, sslexception

I am trying to parse JSON from a http call and I have successfully done it. But when i try to parse same data from https it gives me the following exception...

> 06-28 12:23:37.629: W/System.err(3987): javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate

Could someone please help me understand what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Yuor problem here is not parsing the json but rather the lack of appropriate certificate.

[This](http://javaskeleton.blogspot.co.uk/2010/07/avoiding-peer-not-authenticated-with.html) might help you.